# Decode with base64 a text file gzipped and read it

Tags: perl, base64, gzip

I retrieve from a system a text file which has as been (in order):

1. gzipped
2. encoded with base64

So I would like in Perl to decode it, unzip it and read it without passing by intermediate file.

I tried the following:

```
use Compress::Zlib;
use MIME::Base64;

my $workingDir = "./log/";
my $inputFile =  $workingDir . "log_result_base64.txt";
my $readtmp ='';

open (INPFIC, $inputFile) or die "ERROR: Impossible to open file     ($inputFile)\n";
while (my $buf = <INPFIC> ) {
   $readtmp .= decode_base64($buf);
}
close(INPFIC);

my $output = uncompress($readtmp);

print $output;
```

But it does not work, the $output variable is still undef.

[Edit]

I gave up to do it by passing only by Variable.
I changed my script by creating a new file at each stage:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError) ;
use MIME::Base64;

my $inputFile =  $workingDir . "log_inbase64.txt";
my $inputFilegz =  $workingDir . "log.txt.gz";
my $inputFileuncomp =  $workingDir . "log.txt";

my @out;
my @readtmp;
my $readtmp;

# Reading the file encoded in base64
open (INPFIC, $inputFile) or die "ERROR: Impossible to open file     ($inputFile)\n";
my @readtmp = <INPFIC>;
close(INPFIC);
$readtmp = join('',@readtmp);

# Decode in base64 to retreive a Gzip file
my $out = decode_base64($readtmp);
open my $fh, '>', $inputFilegz or die $!;
binmode $fh;
print $fh $out;
close $fh;

# Decompress the early created gzip file
gunzip $inputFilegz  => $inputFileuncomp
    or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";

# Reading the Text file
open (INPFIC,  $inputFileuncomp) or die "ERROR: Impossible to open file     ($inputFileuncomp )\n";
my @out = <INPFIC>;
close(INPFIC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uncompress` method does not work for gzipped data.

[IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip) can use scalar references instead of file names if you want to keep everything in memory.

Sample code:

```perl
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw( gunzip $GunzipError );
use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 );

my $tmp = decode_base64 do {
  local $/;
  <DATA>
};

gunzip \$tmp => \my $data or die "Could not gunzip: $GunzipError";
print $data;

__DATA__
H4sIAHWHLlUAAwvJyCxWAKLi/NxUhZLU4hKFlMSSRC4AsSDaaxcAAAA=
```

Should produce:

```
This is some test data
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the whole file in a string before decode:

```
local $/ = undef;
my $str = <INPFIC>
my $dec = decode_base64 $str;

my $uncom = uncompress($dec)
```

Comment: I just tested and I have the same result has in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

According to Compress::Zlib doc, try to open and read in same time:

```
my $workingDir = "./log/";
my $inputFile =  $workingDir . "log_result_base64.txt";
my $buffer;
my $output;
my $gz = gzopen($inputFile,"rb")
             or die "Cannot open $inputFile: $gzerrno\n" ;

        while ( $gz->gzread($buffer) > 0 ){
               $output .= decode_base64 $buffer;
        }

        die "Error reading from $inputFile: $gzerrno" . ($gzerrno+0) . "\n"
            if $gzerrno != Z_STREAM_END ;

        $gz->gzclose();
print $output;
```

Comment: In my case I have to décode in base64 the file before decompress it.

Comment: A zip file is not a string and not encoded text. It may contain text files, but that's not the same thing. It's just binary data.